# Arduino + PN532 with chip TSD9471 not work with EMV card

Tags: arduino, nfc, payment, emv

I have two PN532 devices, first with chip TSD9471 and second with TSD4331. I try to read an EMV bankcard, and have some trouble.

The device with TSD4331 reads fine, and the device with tsd9471 always returns fail on `nfc.inListPassiveTarget();` with card, but works fine with ApplePay.

How can I make it universal?

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471091/2373819, may be check the firmware version with the "GetFirmwareVersion" command

Comment: Thank for link, but it's not my solution. I can not make any APDUs because PN532 "not see" nfc-card

Comment: The link was more as a pointer that `inListPassiveTarget` is not the best method of card detection and that it might not be the chip numbers you referenced being the cause but the differences in the firmware version has been noted to have an effect on Tag enumeration.