# libnfc with ACR122U gives no response on SELECT (by AID) APDU

Tags: nfc, apdu, hce, acr122, lib-nfc

See [NFC reader "SELECT (by AID)" APDU is not routed to Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50316799/2425802) on debugging and eventual results. TL;DR the reader might simply be defunct.

---

I have ACR122U nfc reader. I try to run this example http://www.nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc:APDU_example#apdu_example.c on my Ubuntu machine.

This is the log output I get when I tap my Android device (should be in HCE mode) to the reader:

```
./apdu_example
debug   libnfc.general  log_level is set to 3
debug   libnfc.general  allow_autoscan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  allow_intrusive_scan is set to false
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) defined by user
./apdu_example uses libnfc libnfc-1.7.1
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    device found: Bus 001 Device 088 Name     ACS ACR122
debug   libnfc.general  1 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    3 element(s) have been decoded from "acr122_usb:001:088"
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 62 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 81 00 3b 00
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    ACR122 PICC Operating Parameters
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00     51 00 00
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 01 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   GetFirmwareVersion
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 02 d4 02
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 08 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 03 32 01 06 07 90 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   SetParameters
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 03 d4 12 14
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 04 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 13 90 00
debug   libnfc.general  "ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface" (acr122_usb:001:088) has been claimed.
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   ReadRegister
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 0c d4 06 63 02 63 03 63 0d 63 38 63 3d
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 09 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 07 00 00 00 00 00 90 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   PN53X_REG_CIU_TxMode (Defines the transmission data rate and framing during transmission)
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   PN53X_REG_CIU_RxMode (Defines the transmission data rate and framing during receiving)
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   WriteRegister
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 08 d4 08 63 02 80 63 03 80
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 04 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 09 90 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   RFConfiguration
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 04 d4 32 01 00
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 04 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 33 90 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   RFConfiguration
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 04 d4 32 01 01
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 04 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 33 90 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   RFConfiguration
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 06 d4 32 05 ff ff ff
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 04 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 33 90 00
NFC reader: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
Polling for target...
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   ReadRegister
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00     00 00 0e d4 06 63 02 63 03 63 05 63 38 63 3c 63 3d
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 0a 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 07     80 80 43 00 10 00 90 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   InListPassiveTarget
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   No timeout
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00     00 00 04 d4 4a 01 00
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    RX: 80 0e 00 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 d5 4b     01 01 08 03 20 04 01 02 03 04 90 00
Target detected!
=> a4 04 00 07 f0 01 02 03 04 05 06 00
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   InDataExchange
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Timeout value: 5000
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00     00 00 0f d4 40 01 a4 04 00 07 f0 01 02 03 04 05 06 00
res from transceive: -6
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   InDataExchange
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Timeout value: 5000
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    TX: 6f 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00     00 00 0f d4 40 01 a4 04 00 07 f0 01 02 03 04 05 06 00
```

Basically I can see that my Android device is seen by the reader as I can see the UID `(01 02 03 04)` (or another UID if I tap another device). After that transmitting `select AID` apdu just timeouts and I can see no relevant response in my Android logs.

On the Android device I have an application installed with the AID I am trying to select - `f0 01 02 03 04 05 06`.

Can this be a problem with this particular reader? There are other ADPUs which also seem to stop the reader from responding, e.g. `FF 00 00 00 02 D4 04` just gives me no response. Can I diagnose the hardware somehow?

Comment: related issues I have with this reader:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294970/android-acr122u-nfc-integration
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316799/nfc-reader-select-aid-adpu-is-not-routed-to-android-device